# Como filtrar dados de uma tabela do Parse.com

Tags: php, javascript, parse

Quero filtrar certas linhas de uma tabela no [Parse](http://parse.com/) para ser mostrado em um blog, e não sei como seria para fazer uma pesquisa nas postagens ou para filtrar posts que não estão prontos para serem exibidos.

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Pesquisar "Google" e vai retornar somente as linhas que possuem o termo pesquisado em **Title** ou **Body**.
- Filtrar somente as linhas que tem como valor **False** na coluna **Draft**

Eu não sei como seria esse código em `PHP` usando `CURL` e preciso de ajuda.

Comment: Olá Iago, a requisição ao PHP é feita via socket ou você está se referindo ao [`Parse PHP SDK`](https://parse.com/products/php)? Se você criar questões mais completas como é pedido no link http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve talvez você obtenha mais respostas, pois se não apenas pessoas que estiver fazendo trabalhos *exatamente* iguais ao seu que irão conseguir lhe ajudar, pois no momento não tem como saber o que exatamente você fez para ter uma noção de onde começar e isto limita muito a chances de obter uma resposta. Até mais

Comment: Se puder publicar o HTML da página, iria ajudar ou o link.